# How to scroll specific div to top of iframe when click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I searched too much but not found any working answer that resolved my problem. As shown in images i want to scroll/show selected div (when click) to top of iframe. I try to use jquery scrolltop from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll but code not working for me because it works on id and i have classes in divs. But, i edit code to work with classes but, when i run code href="#0" behave like url address and when I click on div nothing happens. can their is any way to replace "a" tag with some another tag to resolve problem.

This is my source code from Dbimage.php page :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
   <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".ScrollTop").on('click', function(event) {
          if (this.hash !== "") {
           event.preventDefault();
           var hash = this.hash;
          $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 800, function()
           {
         // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
         window.location.hash = hash;
     });
  } // End if
  });
  });
  </script>

 <style>
  body, html
  {
     height: 100%;
   }
  .GalleryContentDiv 
  {
     min-height: 300px;
  }
  </style>

  </head>
    <body>

 <a class="ScrollTop" href="#0"> 
  <div class="GalleryContentDiv" id="#0" style="border:1px solid transparent; margin-top:30px; ">

     <!-- contents for great cities 1-->
      </div><br>
  </a> 
     <a  class="ScrollTop" href="#1">
  <div class="GalleryContentDiv" id="#1" style="border:1px solid transparent; margin-top:30px; ">

     <!-- contents for nature 2-->
     </div><br>
     </a>
    </body>
   </html>
```

This is my Iframe code :

```
<iframe id="iframe-Db-Gallery"
 src="http://localhost/HtmlFormGallery/DbImage.php"
 style="width: 95%;height: 350px;margin-left: 4%;" marginheight="0"  > 
</iframe>
```

Any solution please ?

[image: Great cities 1 div]
[image: Great cities 1 div]

Comment: Why don't you want to add id to your div?

Comment: because div like great city 1(<div class="GalleryContentDiv">) all.... are retrieve from mysql database using while loop so, id not works their. because its "Unique" so, this is actual problem !

Comment: that means you want scroll to div with same classes?

Comment: You still can add id, when you loop, add an id + i (that you increment in your loop)

Comment: yes scroll top to iframe with class. because i don't able to use ids their.

Comment: yes i try like <div class="GalleryContentDiv" id='.$id.'> but it conflict or what happens thir don't know but not working.

Comment: why  the point in id='.$id.' ? try id="$id"

Comment: its not working "." is the actual way to merg php code to html.

Comment: can you add your code with the loop? I don't understand how you generate your div

Comment: my .php page code is too long so unable to add it here but i can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I know whats the actual problem is,

Instead,

```
<a class="ScrollTop" href="#0"> 
 <div class="GalleryContentDiv" id="#0">
```

I want to use like,

```
<a class="ScrollTop" href="#'.$id.'">

 <div class="GalleryContentDiv" id="'.$id.'">
```

# is only used with href.

$id = 0,1,2,3,etc. and its now working properly in my php page.

Answer (score 0):

Hm I'm still a little unsure as to what you're trying to do ..

But if the divs having no id's is the problem and the page within the iframe is on the same domain as your Dbimage, then you could just wait until the iframe loads and dynamically add an id to each gallery div.

Untested example from the top of my head:

```
document.getElementById('iframe-Db-Gallery').onload= function() {
    //get document of iframe
    var iframeDocument = document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document;
    //find gallery div's within that iframe
    var iGalleries = $(iframeDocument).find(".GalleryContentDiv");

    $.each(iGalleries, function(index, item){
        //loop through each gallery div and give it an id
        $(item).attr("id", "gallery_" + index);
    });
```

};

Comment: No, their is no jquery or javascript i used for scroll top and simply i just bind Dbimage.php page to other index.html page using iframe thats all !

Comment: No, this above code not working on .php page also and on index.html page.I update my above code please see it if it may help you.